# Turning array in main into a global, to later be altered by main?

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables

I have two arrays of the alphabet in the following format:

```
const char plain[26] = {'a','b',....'y','z'} // this is the the full alphabet
const char crypt[26] = {'i','d',....'m','x'}; // this is the the alphabet scrambled
```

The order of the alphabet in both arrays can change depending on input. This change happens in the main function.

The purpose of this is to match the letters of the string to the second, like an encryption. I compare characters to array values.  So it would kind of look like this (simplified)

```
text[3] = 'yes';
changed[3];
if(text[0] == plain[25]){    //would be done under a for loop so 25 would be a changing integer value
    changed[0] = [crypt[25];
}
```

My code works under perfectly under the main function. I wanted to mention my purpose like this because I was having previous problems simply due to the type of array and formatting. And since the array is moved outside, I will probably/am running into those problems again.

---

Now I want to make the arrays global. The actual encryption happens in a function that does not take the arrays as a variable. But I want the function  to have access to them.

Here's what it looks likes right now

```
const char plain[26];
const char crypt[26];
int maint(void){
    const char plain[26] = {'a','b',....'y','z'} \\values get changed here 
    const char crypt[26] = {'i','d',....'m','x'} \\and here
```

While this provides no errors, I dont get an output, I believe the other functions are using a blank array instead of the changed one (if the change even worked).

I've tried different array types, I believe the issue is in initialization or giving the array values.

Edit: To clarify, the two arrays can be in any order. A text file will randomize the order can give it to me in the format:

```
b,r
m,o
l,s
...
...
...
```

Both cases the alphabet is randomized. Where the first column would correspond to the first array (plain), second would be to second array (crypt).

If there's a way to read by columns and store in the format

```
plain = 'bml...'; \\whole alphabet randomized
crypt = 'ros...'; \\whole alphabet randomized
```

That would also work.

Comment: Why not global pointers, e.g. `const char *plain, *crypt;` and then set the pointers to the address of literals, e.g. `plain = "abc...";`, or constant arrays, `const char foo[] = "jkl";` `crypt = foo;`.  You can `#define NCHAR 26` to make the size available globally as well.

Comment: If you want to change the arrays, don't declare them as `const`, obviously.

Comment: Where did you get the commenting style with the double backslashes `\\` from? And what did you do to your compiler to make that actually work?

Comment: That looks like a monoalphabetic [substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). It's horribly insecure, I really hope you're not using it for anything else than toying around.

Answer (score 11):

The `plain` and `crypt` you have in `main` aren't the same as the global ones. Since you declare them again, they're new ones that are only visible in `main`. Thus you're not changing the global ones.

Instead, only declare them once globally and do assignment in the `main` function:

```
char plain[26];

int main(void) {
    memcpy(plain, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 26); //values get changed here
    return 0; // indicate successful program execution
}
```

Also note that there are some syntax errors in

```
const char plain[26] = {'a','b',....'y','z'} \\values get changed here
```

Comments start with `//`, not `\\`, and you need a `;` after a statement. Also, the `int main` should return an `int` in C.

Of course, if you don't need to actually change the memory and only assign it to predefined sets of characters, you can do it like this:

```
const char *plain;

int main(void) {
    plain = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return 0;
}
```

This way you can still read from it with syntax like `plain[5]`, but you can't assign to it with, say `plain[5] = 'a';`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, I do need to change the order of the alphabets in the arrays. I am getting the two arrays from a text file and they can be in any order. Sorry for the syntax errors, that code was just an example to show how I have it formatted.

Comment: In this case you could either use `memcpy` to put the alphabet you read in into the array. Or you can still go with the `const char *` route and use `strdup` to persist the string you read in from the file and assign it to the  `const char*`.

Comment: You can't `memcpy` into an array of `const`.

Comment: @Barmar It lets me do it and I don't even get a warning for it... anyway, I agree that it is a bit sketchy, so I removed the `const` for that snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Remove "const char" before plain and crypt arrays in main function to see the actual issue.

“Const Char” before plan and crypt arrays actually declare two new local char array constants with same name. As “const” char array can only be initialized at the declaration time therefore initialization in main does not throw error because they are not same global conts arrays.

Instead of using const use Const pointer as suggested in [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587576/turning-array-in-main-into-a-global-to-later-be-altered-by-main?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Please describe your thoughts. The answer as such is not of a good quality.

Comment: Don't use adjectives like "below" to refer to other answers. The positions change, and now it's above.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it is that `plain` and `crypt` will both decay to pointers on access (subject to the exceptions in) [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). So why not just use global pointers to begin with that can then be reassigned as needed throughout your code?

This provides the flexibility of assignment from (1) *string literals*; (2) constant arrays; or (3) from *compound literal* initializers. You can `#define` a constant for the size (number of characters) `plain` and `crypt` point to.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NC 3    /* number of chars (26 for you) */

const char *plain, *crypt;  /* global pointers */

void prnchars (const char *arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NC; i++)
        putchar (arr[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
}

int main (void) {

    plain = "abc";              /* assigning literals */
    crypt = "def";

    prnchars (plain);
    prnchars (crypt);

    crypt = "ghi";              /* reassign at will */

    prnchars (crypt);

    const char foo[] = "jkl";   /* constant arrays */
    crypt = foo;

    prnchars (crypt);

    crypt = (const char[]){'m', 'n', 'o'};  /* compound literals */

    prnchars (crypt);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/global_ptr
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
```

It's just another way of looking at the problem.